# Measurable function and the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\,f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}\,$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and derivable on $(a,b)$. By the mean value property, for all $\,x\in (a,b)\,$ there exists $\,\xi_x\in (a,x)\,$ such that $\,f(x)-f(a)=f'\left(\xi_x\right)(x-a)$. Let $\,h:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}\,$ be defined as $\,h(x)=\xi_x$. Is the function $h$ measurable? Is $\,f'\!\circ h\,$ measurable?

The motivation for this question is the following: in an exercise in class, I estimated $\,\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left\lvert F(x)-F(-x)\right\rvert dx\,$ for a certain "good" function $\,F$ using $\,\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left\lvert F'\left(\xi_x\right)\right\rvert 2\left\lvert x\right\rvert dx,\,$ but the professor told me to be careful, as he wasn't sure of the measurability of $\,x\mapsto F'\left(\xi_x\right)$.

Edit: Thank you for your answers. Assuming that $x\mapsto \xi_x$ is well-defined (taking $\xi_x$ as the smallest possible), is it measurable?

Comment: $\xi_x$ is not unique, so $h$ is not well defined.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing. He could choose $\xi_x$ to be the smallest such number though.

Comment: @bartgol how can you assure the "smallest" one exists? Infimum does exist, but doesn't necessarily fulfil the equation.

Comment: What if you can't take the smallest?

Comment: @Vim, see my edit. I am assuming that $f'$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted by others, $h$ is not well-defined. But you can define $h$ to be measurable: $h$ is actually a well-defined correspondence
$$h(x)=\{ξ\in (a,b);\ f(x)−f(a)=f′(ξ)(x−a)\}$$

It is possible to show $h$ is measurable as a correspondence (see for example corollary 18.8 [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=iw&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)) hence by the measurable selection theorem (see theorem 18.13 in the previous link) $h$ admits a measurable selection.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x\to\xi_x$ is not well defined, as you stated it. However, if you make it well defined, for instance saying that $\xi_x$ is the smallest number that satisfy the MVT, then $f'\circ h$ is measurable. This is because

$$
(f'\circ h)(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$$
Since the right hand side is a measurable function, $f'\circ h$ is measurable.

Edit: the only situation where we may not be able to pick the smallest $\xi_x$ is if we have infinitely many. Note: I am assuming that differentiable is intended as "the derivative exists and it is continuous", which is slightly more than the OP specified. If these infinitely many candidate $\xi_x$ are *continuous* segment, than $f$ is locally a line, and since $f'$ is continuous, I can take the minimum of that segment. The other case is if we have an infinite number of candidates for $\xi_x$ that are disjoint. Clearly, there has to be an infimum. But since $f'$ is continuous, then the infimum must have the same derivative, and therefore be a suitable candidate for $\xi_x$.

Comment: Also, how do you arrive at your conclusion?

Comment: Well, the right hand side is the quotient of two measurable functions, so it is measurable. Since LHS=RHS, the LHS is also measurable.

Comment: I know LHS is measurable. But how do you show $h$ is measurable itself?

Comment: You can't, I'm afraid. However, if you assume $f'$ to be not only continuos, but also invertible (i.e.,strictly monotone), then $h(x)=(f')^{-1}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right)$, and you can prove (I think) that the rhs is measurable.